# Integrate two side menus in same Ionic 2 application

Tags: angular, ionic2

I was following some good [example](http://embed.plnkr.co/OeWv0f/preview) in which you can able to create two side menu's (right and left) in same application. The example in the above link is based on Ionic version 1, but i am looking for the same in Ionic v2.

**Expected**

[image]

It should open left menu when we click left menu button (it should close right menu if already opened)

[image]

and when we click right button this should open right side menu (it should close left side menu if already opened)

[image]

**app.html**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>LEFT MENU</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>                             
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item menuClose>
                <ion-icon name=""></ion-icon>
                ABC
                <ion-icon name="contact" item-right></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menuClose>
                <ion-icon name=""></ion-icon>
                XYZ
                <ion-icon name="person" item-right></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-list-header>User</ion-list-header>
            <ion-item menuClose>
                <ion-icon name=""></ion-icon>
                Forget Password
                <ion-icon name="key" item-right></ion-icon></ion-item>
            <ion-item menuClose>
                <ion-icon name=""></ion-icon>
                Logout
                <ion-icon name="lock" item-right></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**app.component.js**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { WelcomePage } from '../pages/welcome/welcome';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage: any = WelcomePage;

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {}

}
```

**welcome.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="danger">
    <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only (click)="openMenu()">
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>WELCOME</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openUserProfile()">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

**welcome.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-welcome',
  templateUrl: 'welcome.html'
})
export class WelcomePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    public menu: MenuController) {

    menu.enable(true);

  }    

  openMenu() {
    this.menu.toggle();
  }

  openUserProfile(){
      // how to open another (right) menu
  }

}
```

Please guide me with some good examples and concept.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few code addition and i have achieved the objective.

**app.html**

*Description: Add two menu's with side='left/right' and provide id's*

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="left" id="menu1">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>LEFT MENU</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>                             
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item menuClose>
                <ion-icon name=""></ion-icon>
                ABC
                <ion-icon name="contact" item-right></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menuClose>
                <ion-icon name=""></ion-icon>
                XYZ
                <ion-icon name="person" item-right></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>               
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" id="menu2">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="danger">
            <ion-title>USER PROFILE</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item menuClose>
                <ion-icon name=""></ion-icon>
                Forget Password
                <ion-icon name="key" item-right></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menuClose>
                <ion-icon name=""></ion-icon>
                Logout
                <ion-icon name="lock" item-right></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**app.component.js**

*no change in app.js*

**welcome.html**

*Description: Define click event that call a function with parameter. As both the side menu are calling the same function let's pass some parameter so that in welcome.ts we can use those parameter's to open particular side menu's*

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="danger">
    <ion-buttons left>
        <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openMenu('main')">
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>WELCOME</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openMenu('user')">
            <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

**welcome.ts**

*Description: In the 'openMenu' function based on the parameter that we get let's add 'IF' condition that will be responsible to handle which side menu to be invoked. To open particular menu, set that menu enable to 'true' and other menu's to 'false' as defined in below code*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-welcome',
  templateUrl: 'welcome.html'
})
export class WelcomePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    public menu: MenuController) {

    menu.enable(true);

  }  

  openMenu(evt) {
      if(evt === "main"){
         this.menu.enable(true, 'menu1');
         this.menu.enable(false, 'menu2');
      }else{
         this.menu.enable(true, 'menu2');
         this.menu.enable(false, 'menu1');
      }
      this.menu.toggle();
  }

}
```

So that's it. We have achieved our objective to handle **Two side menu on single page in Ionic 2**.

Guys if you have any better suggestion's please guide us.

Have a good day..!

Comment: You can also use menuToggle="left" / menuToggle="right" as an attribute of the button / element you use to display the menu (if you only have 2).

Comment: Thank you @LucianoFantuzzi for your valuable input. According to [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuToggle/) also this is the perfect way to handle multiple menu's display position.